# How to combine these five tables either using {longtable} to show these tables are continued?

Tags: longtable, format

I am new to this community. My summary statistic tables are weird... I want to combine all these five tables either using {longtable} commend to show these tables are continued under the main title Summary Statistics.
Please help me. Thanks so much!  If there are other ways that can make these tables look better, I would like to take that！Any advice would be wonderful!

```
\clearpage
\begin{table}[htbp]
\vspace{-33pt}
\footnotesize
\caption{Summary Statistic}
This table reports summary statistics of the different sample sizes, including the whole sample during the period from 2012 to 2014, the sample during the period from 2012 to 2013 and from 2013 to 2014, the sample during 2013, and the sample during 2014. Panel A shows Internet user status. Panel B shows individual characteristics. Panel C shows the summary statistics of residential LTE broadband availability. The sample period in all three panels is from 2013 to 2014.\\
\label{Summary_statistic}
\topmargin=-25pt
\begin{center}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
                    &           N&        Mean&          SD&         Min&         Max\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Sample 1: 2012-2014 Sample}}\\\cmidrule{1-1} \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{\textit{Panel A: Internet User}}}\\
%\textbf{\textit{Panel A: Internet User &            &            &            &            &            \\
HeavyUser           &      76,763&       0.359&       0.480&           0&           1\\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{\textit{Panel B: Individual Characteristics:}}}&            &            &            &            &            \\
Foreigner           &      76,763&       0.032&       0.177&           0&           1\\
Female              &      76,763&       0.549&       0.498&           0&           1\\
Parental Status     &      76,763&       0.409&       0.492&           0&           1\\
Household Size      &      76,763&       2.619&       1.360&           1&          10\\
Active Employment status&      76,763&       0.488&       0.500&           0&           1\\
Divorced/Seperated  &      76,763&       0.084&       0.277&           0&           1\\
Married             &      76,763&       0.644&       0.479&           0&           1\\
Single              &      76,763&       0.178&       0.382&           0&           1\\
Widow               &      76,763&       0.094&       0.291&           0&           1\\
Age                 &      76,763&      49.203&      17.682&          15&          85\\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{\textit{Panel C: LTE Availability:}}}&            &            &            &            &            \\
Urban LTE Availability&      76,763&       0.606&       0.335&           0&           1\\
Rural LTE Availability&      76,763&       0.223&       0.310&           0&           1\\
Overall LTE availability &      76,763&       0.480&       0.378&           0&           1\\
\\\midrule
\textbf{Sample 2: 2013-2014 Sample}\\\cmidrule{1-1} \textbf{\textit{Panel A: Internet User Status:}}&            &            &            &            &            \\
HeavyUser           &      52,053&       0.372&       0.483&           0&           1\\
\textbf{\textit{Panel B: Individual Characteristics:}}&            &            &            &            &            \\
Foreigner           &      52,053&       0.032&       0.177&           0&           1\\
Female              &      52,053&       0.551&       0.497&           0&           1\\
Parental Status     &      52,053&       0.405&       0.491&           0&           1\\
Household Size      &      52,053&       2.634&       1.394&           1&          10\\
Active Employment status&      52,053&       0.487&       0.500&           0&           1\\
Divorced/Seperated  &      52,053&       0.084&       0.277&           0&           1\\
Married             &      52,053&       0.646&       0.478&           0&           1\\
Single              &      52,053&       0.175&       0.380&           0&           1\\
Widow               &      52,053&       0.095&       0.293&           0&           1\\
Age                 &      52,053&      49.449&      17.755&          15&          85\\
\textbf{\textit{Panel C: LTE Availability:}}&            &            &            &            &            \\
Urban LTE Availability&      52,053&       0.726&       0.266&           0&           1\\
Rural LTE Availability&      52,053&       0.286&       0.334&           0&           1\\
Overall LTE availability &      52,053&       0.581&       0.364&           0&           1\\
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Sample 3: 2012-2013 Sample}}\\\cmidrule{1-1} \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{\textit{Panel A: Internet User:}}}&            &            &            &            &            \\
HeavyUser           &      49,710&       0.337&       0.473&           0&           1\\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{\textit{Panel B: Individual Characteristics:}}}&            &            &            &            &            \\
Foreigner           &      49,710&       0.031&       0.173&           0&           1\\
Female              &      49,710&       0.544&       0.498&           0&           1\\
Parental Status     &      49,710&       0.409&       0.492&           0&           1\\
Household Size      &      49,710&       2.610&       1.340&           1&          10\\
Active Employment status&      49,710&       0.491&       0.500&           0&           1\\
Divorced/Seperated  &      49,710&       0.084&       0.278&           0&           1\\
Married             &      49,710&       0.643&       0.479&           0&           1\\
Single              &      49,710&       0.183&       0.387&           0&           1\\
Widow               &      49,710&       0.090&       0.286&           0&           1\\
Age                 &      49,710&      48.588&      17.574&          15&          85\\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{\textit{Panel C: LTE Availability:}}}&            &            &            &            &            \\
Urban LTE Availability&      49,710&       0.472&       0.324&           0&           1\\
Rural LTE Availability&      49,710&       0.140&       0.251&           0&           1\\
Overall LTE availability &      49,710&       0.358&       0.341&           0&           1\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}




\begin{table}[htbp]
\vspace{-30pt}
\footnotesize
\caption{Summary Statistic}
\label{Summary_statistic}
\topmargin=-23pt
\begin{center}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
                    &           N&        Mean&          SD&         Min&         Max\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Sample 1: 2013 Sample}}\\\cmidrule{1-1} \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{\textit{Panel A: Internet User:}}}&            &            &            &            &            \\
HeavyUser           &      25,000&       0.343&       0.475&           0&           1\\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{\textit{Panel B: Individual Characteristics:}}}&            &            &            &            &            \\
Foreigner           &      25,000&       0.030&       0.170&           0&           1\\
Female              &      25,000&       0.543&       0.498&           0&           1\\
Parental Status     &      25,000&       0.402&       0.490&           0&           1\\
Household Size      &      25,000&       2.633&       1.393&           1&          10\\
Active Employment status&      25,000&       0.491&       0.500&           0&           1\\
Divorced/Seperated  &      25,000&       0.085&       0.279&           0&           1\\
Married             &      25,000&       0.644&       0.479&           0&           1\\
Single              &      25,000&       0.182&       0.386&           0&           1\\
Widow               &      25,000&       0.089&       0.285&           0&           1\\
Age                 &      25,000&      48.492&      17.631&          15&          85\\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{\textit{Panel C: LTE Availability:}}}&            &            &            &            &            \\
Urban LTE Availability&      25,000&       0.591&       0.279&           0&           1\\
Rural LTE Availability&      25,000&       0.187&       0.289&           0&           1\\
Overall LTE availability &      25,000&       0.449&       0.343&           0&           1\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Sample 1: 2014 Sample}}\\\cmidrule{1-1} \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{\textit{Panel A: Internet User:}}}&            &            &            &            &            \\
HeavyUser           &      27,053&       0.400&       0.490&           0&           1\\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{\textit{Panel B: Individual Characteristics:}}}&            &            &            &            &            \\
Foreigner           &      27,053&       0.035&       0.184&           0&           1\\
Female              &      27,053&       0.559&       0.497&           0&           1\\
Parental Status     &      27,053&       0.408&       0.492&           0&           1\\
Household Size      &      27,053&       2.635&       1.395&           1&          10\\
Active Employment status&      27,053&       0.483&       0.500&           0&           1\\
Divorced/Seperated  &      27,053&       0.083&       0.276&           0&           1\\
Married             &      27,053&       0.648&       0.478&           0&           1\\
Single              &      27,053&       0.169&       0.374&           0&           1\\
Widow               &      27,053&       0.100&       0.301&           0&           1\\
Age                 &      27,053&      50.333&      17.824&          15&          85\\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{\textit{Panel C: LTE Availability:}}}&            &            &            &            &            \\
Urban LTE Availability&      27,053&       0.851&       0.179&           0&           1\\
Rural LTE Availability&      27,053&       0.377&       0.347&           0&           1\\
Overall LTE availability &      27,053&       0.703&       0.339&           0&           1\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  What document class are you using?  If you could extend this to be compilable (beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`), that would give a potential helper something to experiment with.

Comment: Your write-up is a bit confusing. You mention five tables, but I can only spot three. Please clarify.

Comment: Assuming all the tabulars have the same layout, you should have no problem.  If they have diffferent layouts, you can create multiple longtables consecutively.  The big thing is to decide what you want in the first head and what you want at the top of every page after.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution provides three separate `longtable` environments.

[image]

[image]

In the following code, note the use of `\\*` instead of `\\` to indicate when page breaks are not allowed. Observe also that it's not necessary to invoke either `\footnotesize` or `\scriptsize`.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\sisetup{group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits=4}

\begin{document}

The following tables report summary statistics of various datasets. 
The whole sample comprises the period from 2012 to 2014; the 
subsample periods are from 2012 to 2013, from 2013 to 2014, 2013, 
and 2014. Panel~A shows Internet user status, Panel~B shows 
individual characteristics, and Panel~C shows the summary statistics 
of residential LTE broadband availability. The sample period in all 
three panels is from 2013 to 2014.


%% first longtable
\begin{longtable}{@{} l S[table-format=5.0] 
                   *{2}{S[table-format=2.3]} 
                   *{2}{S[table-format=2.0]} @{}}

\caption{Summary Statistics I}
\label{Summary_statistics1}\\
\toprule
& {$N$} & {Mean} & {SD} & {Min} & {Max}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

Table \thetable, cont'd \\[1ex]
\addlinespace
\toprule
& {$N$} & {Mean} & {SD} & {Min} & {Max}\\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule 
\multicolumn{6}{r@{}}{\small\itshape(continued on following page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
\textbf{2012--2014 Sample} \\*    
HeavyUser           &      76763& 0.359& 0.480&    0&    1\\ 
\addlinespace
Foreigner           &      76763& 0.032& 0.177&    0&    1\\
Female              &      76763& 0.549& 0.498&    0&    1\\
Parental Status     &      76763& 0.409& 0.492&    0&    1\\
Household Size      &      76763& 2.619& 1.360&    1&   10\\
Active Employment status&  76763& 0.488& 0.500&    0&    1\\
Divorced/Seperated  &      76763& 0.084& 0.277&    0&    1\\
Married             &      76763& 0.644& 0.479&    0&    1\\
Single              &      76763& 0.178& 0.382&    0&    1\\
Widow               &      76763& 0.094& 0.291&    0&    1\\
Age                 &      76763&49.203&17.682&   15&   85\\
\addlinespace
Overall LTE availability&  76763& 0.480& 0.378&    0&    1\\

\addlinespace
\textbf{2013--2014 Subsample} \\*       
HeavyUser           &      52053& 0.372& 0.483&    0&    1\\
\addlinespace
Foreigner           &      52053& 0.032& 0.177&    0&    1\\
Female              &      52053& 0.551& 0.497&    0&    1\\
Parental Status     &      52053& 0.405& 0.491&    0&    1\\
Household Size      &      52053& 2.634& 1.394&    1&   10\\
Active Employment status&  52053& 0.487& 0.500&    0&    1\\
Divorced/Seperated  &      52053& 0.084& 0.277&    0&    1\\
Married             &      52053& 0.646& 0.478&    0&    1\\
Single              &      52053& 0.175& 0.380&    0&    1\\
Widow               &      52053& 0.095& 0.293&    0&    1\\
Age                 &      52053&49.449&17.755&   15&   85\\
\addlinespace
Overall LTE availability & 52053& 0.581& 0.364&    0&    1\\

\end{longtable}


%% second longtable
\begin{longtable}{@{} l S[table-format=5.0] 
                   *{2}{S[table-format=2.3]} 
                   *{2}{S[table-format=2.0]} @{}}

\caption{Summary Statistics II} \label{Summary_statistics2}\\
\toprule
& {$N$} & {Mean} & {SD} & {Min} & {Max}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

Table \thetable, cont'd\\[1ex]
\toprule
& {$N$} & {Mean} & {SD} & {Min} & {Max}\\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule 
\multicolumn{6}{r@{}}{\small\itshape(continued on following page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
\textbf{Sample 1: 2012--2014}\\*
\addlinespace

\textit{Panel A.} Internet User\\*
HeavyUser           &      76763& 0.359& 0.480&    0&    1\\

\addlinespace
\textit{Panel B.} Individual Characteristics \\*
Foreigner           &      76763& 0.032& 0.177&    0&    1\\
Female              &      76763& 0.549& 0.498&    0&    1\\
Parental Status     &      76763& 0.409& 0.492&    0&    1\\
Household Size      &      76763& 2.619& 1.360&    1&   10\\
Active Employment status&  76763& 0.488& 0.500&    0&    1\\
Divorced/Seperated  &      76763& 0.084& 0.277&    0&    1\\
Married             &      76763& 0.644& 0.479&    0&    1\\
Single              &      76763& 0.178& 0.382&    0&    1\\
Widow               &      76763& 0.094& 0.291&    0&    1\\
Age                 &      76763&49.203&17.682&   15&   85\\

\addlinespace
\textit{Panel C.} LTE Availability \\*
Urban LTE Availability&    76763& 0.606& 0.335&    0&    1\\
Rural LTE Availability&    76763& 0.223& 0.310&    0&    1\\
Overall LTE availability & 76763& 0.480& 0.378&    0&    1\\

\addlinespace\addlinespace

\textbf{Sample 2: 2013--2014}\\*
\addlinespace
\textit{Panel A.} Internet User Status\\*
HeavyUser           &      52053& 0.372& 0.483&    0&    1\\

\addlinespace
\textit{Panel B.} Individual Characteristics \\*
Foreigner           &      52053& 0.032& 0.177&    0&    1\\
Female              &      52053& 0.551& 0.497&    0&    1\\
Parental Status     &      52053& 0.405& 0.491&    0&    1\\
Household Size      &      52053& 2.634& 1.394&    1&   10\\
Active Employment status&  52053& 0.487& 0.500&    0&    1\\
Divorced/Seperated  &      52053& 0.084& 0.277&    0&    1\\
Married             &      52053& 0.646& 0.478&    0&    1\\
Single              &      52053& 0.175& 0.380&    0&    1\\
Widow               &      52053& 0.095& 0.293&    0&    1\\
Age                 &      52053&49.449&17.755&   15&   85\\

\addlinespace
\textit{Panel C.} LTE Availability \\*
Urban LTE Availability&    52053& 0.726& 0.266&    0&    1\\
Rural LTE Availability&    52053& 0.286& 0.334&    0&    1\\
Overall LTE availability&  52053& 0.581& 0.364&    0&    1\\

\addlinespace\addlinespace
\textbf{Sample 3: 2012--2013}\\*

\addlinespace
\textit{Panel A.} Internet User \\*
HeavyUser           &      49710& 0.337& 0.473&    0&    1\\

\addlinespace
\textit{Panel B.} Individual Characteristics \\*
Foreigner           &      49710& 0.031& 0.173&    0&    1\\
Female              &      49710& 0.544& 0.498&    0&    1\\
Parental Status     &      49710& 0.409& 0.492&    0&    1\\
Household Size      &      49710& 2.610& 1.340&    1&   10\\
Active Employment status&  49710& 0.491& 0.500&    0&    1\\
Divorced/Seperated  &      49710& 0.084& 0.278&    0&    1\\
Married             &      49710& 0.643& 0.479&    0&    1\\
Single              &      49710& 0.183& 0.387&    0&    1\\
Widow               &      49710& 0.090& 0.286&    0&    1\\
Age                 &      49710&48.588&17.574&   15&   85\\

\addlinespace
\textit{Panel C.} LTE Availability \\*
Urban LTE Availability&    49710& 0.472& 0.324&    0&    1\\
Rural LTE Availability&    49710& 0.140& 0.251&    0&    1\\
Overall LTE availability&  49710& 0.358& 0.341&    0&    1\\

\end{longtable}




\begin{longtable}{@{} l S[table-format=5.0] 
                   *{2}{S[table-format=2.3]} 
                   *{2}{S[table-format=2.0]} @{}}

\caption{Summary Statistics III}
\label{Summary_statistics3}\\

\toprule
& {$N$} & {Mean} & {SD} & {Min} & {Max}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

Table \thetable, cont'd \\[1ex]
\addlinespace
\toprule
& {$N$} & {Mean} & {SD} & {Min} & {Max}\\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule 
\multicolumn{6}{r@{}}{\small\itshape(continued on following page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
\textbf{Sample 1: 2013}\\* 

\addlinespace
\textit{Panel A.} Internet User \\*
HeavyUser           & 25000 & 0.343& 0.475&    0&    1\\

\addlinespace
\textit{Panel B.} Individual Characteristics \\*
Foreigner           & 25000 & 0.030& 0.170&    0&    1\\
Female              & 25000 & 0.543& 0.498&    0&    1\\
Parental Status     & 25000 & 0.402& 0.490&    0&    1\\
Household Size      & 25000 & 2.633& 1.393&    1&   10\\
Active Employment status& 25000 & 0.491& 0.500&0&    1\\
Divorced/Seperated  & 25000 & 0.085& 0.279&    0&    1\\
Married             & 25000 & 0.644& 0.479&    0&    1\\
Single              & 25000 & 0.182& 0.386&    0&    1\\
Widow               & 25000 & 0.089& 0.285&    0&    1\\
Age                 & 25000 &48.492&17.631&   15&   85\\

\addlinespace
\textit{Panel C.} LTE Availability \\*
Urban LTE Availability& 25000 &     0.591& 0.279&    0&    1\\
Rural LTE Availability& 25000 &     0.187& 0.289&    0&    1\\
Overall LTE availability & 25000 &  0.449& 0.343&    0&    1\\

\addlinespace\addlinespace
\textbf{Sample 2: 2014}\\*

\addlinespace
\textit{Panel A.} Internet User \\*
HeavyUser           &     27053& 0.400& 0.490&    0&    1\\

\addlinespace
\textit{Panel B.} Individual Characteristics \\*
Foreigner           &     27053& 0.035& 0.184&    0&    1\\
Female              &     27053& 0.559& 0.497&    0&    1\\
Parental Status     &     27053& 0.408& 0.492&    0&    1\\
Household Size      &     27053& 2.635& 1.395&    1&   10\\
Active Employment status& 27053& 0.483& 0.500&    0&    1\\
Divorced/Seperated  &     27053& 0.083& 0.276&    0&    1\\
Married             &     27053& 0.648& 0.478&    0&    1\\
Single              &     27053& 0.169& 0.374&    0&    1\\
Widow               &     27053& 0.100& 0.301&    0&    1\\
Age                 &     27053&50.333&17.824&   15&   85\\

\addlinespace
\textit{Panel C.} LTE Availability \\*
Urban LTE Availability&   27053& 0.851& 0.179&    0&    1\\
Rural LTE Availability&   27053& 0.377& 0.347&    0&    1\\
Overall LTE availability& 27053& 0.703& 0.339&    0&    1\\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Mico! I will start with your advice to see if I can produce the table that I want to have